How to read the schema of the delta table in snowflake
In snowflake I want to understand, if there is a possibility to get the schema (column names and dataype) of the delta tables in ADLS.
I 'm trying to create a DDL structure ICEBERG Table, and DDL view on top of it for the iceberg table. I have created the EXTERNAL VOLUME, CATALOG etc. I’m able to create the iceberg table. But in order to create the view DDL I need the schema of the delta tables.
If I create a ICEBERG table first and then I can use the desc table to get the columns. I want to create the DDL for both ICEBERG table and VIEW.
Is there any way to read the schea of the delta tables in using EXTERNAL VOLUME or any other approach.
I could find any resources

I would take a look at this link.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-iceberg-table-delta
